# python 2.7 RSA key format is not supported

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

Im new in crypto, and using python. Im trying to decrypt a file using my private key (RSA) but already converted to hexstring. during my testing 
i always get an error " RSA key format is not supported ". Do i still have a way to make this key as a PEM file?

just edited the code and still

```
priv_exp_d =  int("B3F00AF2ABED4453F00E2AC49EB4AF390BA15207B44B3 \
               3ABF8DE88C5BACAA82DA3A2382DE7466AD47294B68B6D47B1916AB89139D008 \    
               6F164EDD95917A5A1879C0C4AE5F970DE3863C7AB5EDF6A87A2880DABB31235 \ 
               AE31285050832C6DD9CC6FD9FD35FB863995032EBBA246CAC384E6FF8EE2ECA \ 
               158FC0724F4710203D6781",16)
public_mod_n = int("CE8A179D3F1811CBEFF09FEB1840EA12D81FB2B4BD0B7A61FACF67809B9A6E5F1B5E237085184B040AA88E2FDDF023FB645F1B85C33F4E39BD96593D28309473AFFB7CAC60FD659215569C8756A51288BF02D859C1269250B32FA4C21A77B951DD53F020CC65640E54D27F98E8BF17CFF717B85F387F47B80F16C57D8951944F",16)
exponent = 65537

_rsa = RSA.construct((public_mod_n, long(exponent),priv_exp_d))
decrypted_aes = _rsa.decrypt(data_to_decrypt)
```

Thanks.

Comment: is the hex string just a single number (d) or was it originally some pkcs1 structure (or pkcs8)?

Comment: actually i got the value from here [link](http://pastebin.com/x1NydTHZ). It's a master key for decrypting ransomware Crysis. This ransomware encrypts the AES key with RSA. So i need to decrypt it to get the AES. Sorry for a dumb question. Just started studying the Crypto

Comment: You need encoded modulus and private exponent. Shouldn't you have 2 hex strings there then?

Comment: hi @MarekKlein, just edited the code above, not sure if im doing it right. anyway, thank you for helping me out.

Comment: How do you know what is the right order of bytes? In other word, how do you know that the byte B3 is the most significant byte and not the least significant byte?

Comment: hi @MarekKlein, thanks for your time i already figure it out. I can already get the private key. I'll modify the code, so hopefully it may help others